# Installed fabric but still getting ' no module fabric.api'

Tags: python, python-2.7, virtualenv, fabric

Currently, I am in a strange situation. I created a virtual environment and installed fabric via command

```
pip install fabric
```

The installation is successfully complete but when I import the module, it shows me 'no module fabric.api'

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem by running below command in the virtual environment.

> pip install fabric

instead of

> sudo pip install fabric

I didn't get the reason but its just working fine now.